# What is the meaning of ±a=±b

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

What does this mean $\pm a=\pm b$

If we say $\pm a=x$ then $x=\pm b$ then $x=b$ or $x=-b$.  So by resubstituting
$\pm a=\pm b$. Or $\pm a=-b$
Hence

$a=b$ or $a=-b$.     Or $a=-b $ or $a=b$

Finally $a=±b$

Is that correct?

Comment: You will need to check the source. Some people agree to make the same choice of sign in all occurrences of $\pm$, some don't.

Comment: The meaning means whatever who wrote it intended it to mean and the meaning may vary depending on who wrote it.  It may be intended to mean that $a=b$ where both $\pm$'s are thought of as being "linked" always being in the same state at the same time (*so it really reads that $a=b$ or $-a=-b$ which of course these mean the same*) or it could be intended to mean as you seem to interpret that $a=b$ or $a=-b$ or $-a=b$ or $-a=-b$ where the $\pm$'s are not linked and may vary individually.

Comment: Note in particular the usage of $\mp$ which is often intended to take the opposite of whatever $\pm$ does at the time, so $1\pm 2\mp 3\pm 4\mp 5$ would always either be $1+2-3+4-5$ or would be $1-2+3-4+5$ with alternating between adding and subtracting.

Comment: The context is important. For example, $x=\pm a=\pm b$ means $x=\pm a$, which we know is $\pm b$ (be it because $a=b$, or $a=-b$, or the disjunction of these).

Comment: If there is no further context, it is ambiguous, you can interpret either as $(a, -a) = (b, -b)$ or as $\{a, -a\} = \{b, -b\}$.  Personally I would use $a=b$ or $a=\pm b$ instead respectively (though the last usage should be more strictly $a\in \{b,-b\}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an expression contains two or more $\pm$ signs, it is unclear if these are "synchronized" or not, and the writer has to make it clear from context.

In your case, there is no satisfactory interpretation:

- if the signs are synchronized, $\pm a=\pm b$ (meaning $a=b\lor -a=-b$) is just $a=b$ and it is illogical to use them at all;
- if the signs are not synchronized, one of them is superfluous and it is clearer to write $a=\pm b$.

Comment: So,in this context,if the given steps are true,them are they synchronised or not?

Comment: @Mathsorbiter: which given steps ???

Comment: Everything after 'then' in the question